# How to select a workspace with .yoxos launcher file?

Tags: yoxos

If I save a .yoxos file there is no dialog coming up that asks me to select a workspace.

The trick is, that the directory in which the .yoxos file is, is the location of the workspace.

I wonder if there is a way to tell yoxos to ask for a workspace.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to ~/.yoxoslauncher/instances/ and find your eclipse instance. The best way to figure this out is to launch eclipse with the yoxos launcher and go to

```
About Eclipse->Installation Details...->Configuration
```

There you see your application folder